# RAR archive password recovery

Tags: encryption, passwords, recovery

Hello guys is there some tool or methodic to get into let's say 12 years old RAR file.

I tried Kraken CMD tool and dictionary attack but it will take ages goes through all passwords.

Unfortunately for me password is around 35 characters. Alphabet is probably [0-9, J, a, m, e, s] so 15 chars.

I tried some removal tools but nothing seems to work.

Or maybe some community of password crackers exists ?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i would recommend hashcat with a mask attack using all you know about the password to reduce the amount if iterations to tolerable, but depending of how much you are sure about the password it still can take years beyond imaginable to crack.
[Neither RAR nor 7Zip formats have any known vulnerabilities when it comes to encryption](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2021/04/breaking-rar5-and-7zip-passwords/) so your best chances are using a service like cloud computing on demand to brute force the RAR password hash (you`ll have to pay for it of course) see if for a miracle the hash is already cracked on a database or searching for some note you left about the password. 
Honestly if the content of the archive does't matter that much, just delete it.